# functional derivative with respect to the partial derivative of the metric with xAct

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, xact

I want to compute the functional derivative with respect to a partial derivative of the metric with the mathematica package xAct.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
DefManifold[M, 4, IndexRange[a, z]]
DefMetric[-1, met[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g", CurvatureRelations -> True]

Ctil[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := 
 RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d] epsilonmet[a, b, -e, -f] RiemannCD[e, f, c,
    d]

DefTensor[pdg[-x, -y, -z], M, Symmetric[{1, 2, 3}]]

L2b = Ctil[g, h, i, j, k, l] // RiemannToChristoffel//ChristoffelToGradMetric 
L2b = L2b /. PD[-a__][met[-b__, -c__]] :> pdg[-a, -b, -c]
VarDL2b = VarL[pdg[-x, -y, -z], CD][L2b] // FullSimplification[] // CollectTensors
```

and the errors that I am getting are of the type:

IndexForm: Attempting to apply IndexForm on <<2>>.
ToCanonical: Unknown expression not canonicalized

Comment: Try asking on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/